# Enable Win32 long paths not working in Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, winapi, path, group-policy

**Windows 10 Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.321)**

I am getting following error while building our java project in command line

> Error while executing process. Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\java": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

I have enabled 'Enable Win32 long paths' option under group policy

> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem

Restarted the system. But still getting same error.

Comment: Ask the vendor of the tool, why they chose to limit the path name to 260 characters. You cannot change system settings to make this work. This is a bug in the software that calls `CreateProcess`.

Comment: @IInspectable `CreateProcess()` is a Win32 API function, and error 206 is `ERROR_FILENAME_EXCED_RANGE`. Per the documentation: "*The maximum length of [lpCommandLine] is 32,768 characters, including the Unicode terminating null character. If lpApplicationName is NULL, the module name portion of lpCommandLine is limited to MAX_PATH characters.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau: In other words: Don't pass NULL for *lpApplicationName*.

Comment: @IInspectable [What is the command line length limit?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031210-00/?p=41553)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: How is that related to your previous comment?

Comment: Can you provide more information? What are you using to build your project? What are your build settings? What is the command line that the build tool tries to execute?

Comment: @andlabs- I am trying to build Java maven project in command prompt (DOS) using maven command ( mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true)

Comment: You'll probably have to talk to the Maven folks then; there's a potential bug in it from what I see. Good luck.